# How to store value from dropdown to use in other php page without action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this code -

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<select name="feature" id="Feature" onchange="myFunction()">
        <?php
        ?>
        <option value > Select Feature</option>
        <?php
        foreach($newFeature as $feat)
        {
            ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $feat;?>"><?php echo $feat;?></option>
            <?php
       }
         ?>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction()
    {
    var x=document.getElementById("Feature");

}
</script>
```

here how can I use cookies or session variable to store selected value and use it in other php page ?

please guide

Comment: If you do not want to submit a form then you will probably need to use Ajax to submit the value to a PHP page which can then do what you want with it. Please read about Ajax [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). To answer this question more fully we would need to know exactly what it is you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this context it is best that you use cookie

I did this for someone else, hop this help you to get an idea of cookie usage.
What this do is keep the selected value set after page refresh by fetching it from cookie, you can fetch it in your desired page instead

> HTML

```
   <select id="selectCurrency">
        <option value="1">US</option>
        <option value="98">RS</option>
        <option value="61">Ind</option>
    </select>
```

**Jquery**

```
//Fetching cookie you can do this in any other page 
$(document).ready(function(e){
var name = "Currency="; //Name of the cookie
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++)
  {
  var c = ca[i].trim();
  if (c.indexOf(name)==0) $('#selectCurrency').val(c.substring(name.length,c.length));
  }
});



//Setting Cookie
$('#selectCurrency').change(function(e)
{
    var cookieVal = "Currency="+$(this).val();
document.cookie = cookieVal ;

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AmarnathRShenoy/HM3Zj/9/

For more check this

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: where I am writing this js code to fetch cookie value. in the same page can I use this "C" in php code ?

Comment: @Satish sure u can use it

Comment: i tired using ajax but it is not working. Can u pls help with this

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HM3Zj/10/)

aa.php - [link](http://pastebin.com/AX58DhBM)

i get this error -  Notice: Undefined index: mapza and then null

Comment: Something like the above link?

Answer (score 1):

Without having submit button you can store selected value in jquery cookie as

```
$.cookie('key', 'value');
```

and in next php page u can get this value by using $_COOKIE variable

Comment: in any other phph script without action or submit ?

Comment: Considering you have select element inside <form></form> and action is defined as name of your php file that takes it to next page

Comment: that wht I am saying I don't want a submit button

Comment: Edited post  you can make use of $.cookie

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to write to your browser localstorage. But it still need to be send als  request parameter to your other php pages. The thing is that php is server side. And the session parameters are hold by your php server. You can store the data als string locally, but you still need to reload it into your new page from the client side.

```
Just an example for using localStorage
// save in the localStorage
if (window.localStorage) {
    var value = "hallo";
    localStorage.setItem("value", value);
}
// load the localStorage 
var value=localStorage.getItem("value");
```

You can now us that in your client

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript cookies ,set the cookies in your function and get this cookie in other page.

here is example  http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `this.value` in select box or replace

```
<select name="feature" id="Feature" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
```

add this  `alert(x)` after `var x=document.getElementById("Feature");` for check

Answer (score 0):

u can submit ur form data to php for process via ajax, and u can do use php to create cookie or session

EXAMPLE:

```
$('#Feature').change(function(){
   $.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     data: $(this).serialize(),
     url: '/process',
     success:function(data,textStatus, jqXHR){
         //do something
     }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
$_SESSION['feature'] = $_POST['feature'];
```